# Match, Index and specific lists

Tags: excel

I want to match specific rows and columns.

If `A2` is matched with `B1`, then return list "ROW 1" in `B2:B151`
If `A5` is matched with `B5` then return list "ROW 4" in `B2:B151`

As explained in the image `B2` is feed by a Dropdown from another sheet (This is not part of the question)
I am trying to override this list in `B2:B151` every time a new match is made.

I haven't got a clue on how to proceed have tried multiple Index and match combination even `Vlookup` which is not viable for this sort of problem.

I was thinking of concatenating all these formulas in `B2`. The reason why I want to use Rows and columns to determine the specific match is that the data in B1 an `A2:A7` is ever-changing and that's the reason why the formula needs to be dynamic.

[image]

Comment: Please post some of your efforts. You need a MATCH inside an INDEX.

Comment: Hi SJR, Yes I used =INDEX(PhaseOneList;MATCH(D1;PhaseArrayList;0)) to get the data from "PhaseArrayList" which is the array name of the data in green in A1:A7 - I can easily get the data inserted from ROW 1 Data which is named "PhaseOneList" however I still need to figure out how to, when A3 is matched with B1 to get list from ROW 2, which is named PhaseTwoList and so on; FX. A4 matched with B1 should return PhaseThreeList.

Comment: sorry correct formula =INDEX(PhaseOneList;**0**;MATCH(D2;PhaseArrayList;0))
PhaseOneList, 0 where 0 is indicating the row number

Comment: OK, that's a start. Please can you add that to your question. So PhaseArrayList is the green cells, PhaseOneList is the row containing "ROW 1 ROW 2 etc", and PhaseTwoList is the row underneath?

Comment: Hi again SJR 7,  Yes precise :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, but I'm not 100% sure of the desired final outcome.

The formula in B1 is

```
=OFFSET($D2,0,MATCH($B$1,PhaseArrayList,0)-1,1,1)
```

and you can just copy that down as many rows as you need. When you change the value in B1 it will update.

The Offset says says start at D2, go 0 rows down, go to the right the number of columns equal to the match of B1 less 1. So if C is in B1 the match returns 3 and the offset goes across 2 columns, i.e. to column F (ROW 3).

(Btw would be less confusing if you labelled them columns!)

[image]

Comment: You are absolutely amazing. Thank you lesson learned I will dig into Offsets for future use cases. Thanks :) I can vote yet but will come back when my Rep is higher thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it worked. You can accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Done! Thanks again